# PyQT5 with matplotlib figure, the event loop is already running

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a program, which by clicking button on PyQT app shows matplotlib figure in another window.
When i click button, that windows shows, but on Figure nothing happends and in console i get this:

QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running

I have a 3 classes and file with PyQT5 Gui.
3 class get values from TextEdits, call second class, which calculating and return lists with x, y coords to show it on the matplotlib figure (first class). I find different ways to solve this, but there is examples for simple cases and i don't understand how i can apply them solutions to my code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from pythongui4 import Ui_MainWindow
from scipy import integrate
from random import randint
from math import sin, cos, pi
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import sys
import time


# GLOBAL CONSTANTS:

g = 9.80665 # (Gravity acceleration on the Earth), m/s^2


class GraphTrajectoryAnimation(animation.FuncAnimation):
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, xlim, ylim, parent=None, m=50, lw=3, width=6, height=4):
        """
         Where x, y - NumPy lists with coordinates, color - color of line (default - choose by Random)
                        height, width, dpi - hw, dpi of the figure from PyLab.
        """
        self.figure, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width, height))
        self.ax.set_xlim([0, xlim])
        self.ax.set_ylim([0, ylim])
        self.graphfunction, = self.ax.plot([], [], color='blue', lw=2)
        self.dot, = self.ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='red')
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.m = m
        self.color = color
        self.lw = lw

    def animation(self, i, x, y, m, color):
        """ Definition of a matplotlib animation. """
        if i * m >= len(x) or i * m >= len(y):
            self.graphfunction.set_data(x[:i*m], y[:i*m])
        else:
            self.graphfunction.set_data(x[:i*m], y[:i*m])
            self.dot.set_data(x[i*m], y[i*m])

    def graph(self, interval=50):
        """ Definition of cycle FuncAnimation, which call animation. """
        self.graph_id = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.animation,
                                            fargs=(self.x, self.y, self.m, self.color),
                                            repeat=False, interval=interval, frames=400)

    def showfigure(self):
        """ Call the graph function and displays it on the figure. """
        self.graph()
        plt.show()


class SolveSystemOfADifferentialEquations:
    def __init__(self, k, angle, v0, m, ws, tlimit=20):
        self.k = k
        self.angle = angle
        self.m = m
        self.ws = ws
        self.v0 = v0
        self.v0_x = self.v0 * cos(self.angle)
        self.v0_y = self.v0 * sin(self.angle)
        self.kdivm = self.k / self.m
        self.time = np.arange(0, tlimit, 0.0005)

    def xmodel(self, X, t):
        x = X[0]
        dx = X[1]
        zdot = [ [], [] ]
        zdot[0] = dx
        zdot[1] = -self.kdivm * dx + self.ws
        return zdot

    def ymodel(self, Y, t):
        y = Y[0]
        dy = Y[1]
        zdot = [ [], [] ]
        zdot[0] = dy
        zdot[1] = -g - self.kdivm * dy
        return zdot

    def solveX(self):
        x = integrate.odeint(self.xmodel, [0, self.v0_x], self.time)
        return x

    def solveY(self):
        y = integrate.odeint(self.ymodel, [0, self.v0_y], self.time)
        return y


class MainCommunicationWithGui:
    def startbutton(self):
        self.getvalues()

    def getvalues(self):
        ws = float(ui.textEdit_1.toPlainText())
        m = float(ui.textEdit_2.toPlainText())
        if m == 0:
            return False
        k = float(ui.textEdit_3.toPlainText())
        angle = float(ui.textEdit_4.toPlainText()) * (pi / 180)
        v0 = float(ui.textEdit_5.toPlainText())
        xlim = float(ui.textEdit_7.toPlainText())
        ylim = float(ui.textEdit_8.toPlainText())
        x, y = self.tosystem(k, angle, v0, m, ws)
        self.figureinit(x, y, xlim, ylim)

    def tosystem(self, k, angle, v0, m, ws):
        system = SolveSystemOfADifferentialEquations(k, angle, v0, m, ws)
        Xi = np.array(system.solveY())
        Yi = np.array(system.solveY())
        x = []
        y = []
        for j in range(1, len(Yi)):
            if Yi[j][0] > 0:
                x.append(Yi[j][0])
                y.append(Xi[j][0])
        return x, y

    def figureinit(self, x, y, xlim, ylim):
        colors = ['blue', 'green', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'black']
        figure = GraphTrajectoryAnimation(x, y, colors[randint(0, 4)] , xlim, ylim)
        figure.showfigure()

    def exitbutton(self):
        sys.exit(1)

    def initbuttons(self):
        ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.startbutton)
        ui.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.exitbutton)

def main():
    global ui, app
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    communicate = MainCommunicationWithGui()
    communicate.initbuttons()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use a GUI then you should not use pyplot but the canvas of the respective backend so that there is no conflict of event loops.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (
    FigureCanvas,
    NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar,
)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from pythongui4 import Ui_MainWindow


g = 9.80665  # (Gravity acceleration on the Earth), m/s^2


class Canvas(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(
        self, color, xlim=1, ylim=1, m=50, lw=3, width=6, height=4, parent=None
    ):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(width, height))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self))

        self.ax = self.figure.subplots()
        self.ax.set_xlim([0, xlim])
        self.ax.set_ylim([0, ylim])
        (self.graphfunction,) = self.ax.plot([], [], color="blue", lw=2)
        (self.dot,) = self.ax.plot([], [], "o", color="red")

        self._color = color
        self._xlim = xlim
        self._ylim = ylim
        self._m = m
        self._lw = lw

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list, list)
    def update_values(self, x, y):
        self.x = x[:]
        self.y = y[:]
        self.graph()

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, color):
        self._color = color

    @property
    def xlim(self):
        return self._xlim

    @xlim.setter
    def xlim(self, xlim):
        self._xlim = xlim

    @property
    def ylim(self):
        return self._ylim

    @color.setter
    def ylim(self, ylim):
        self._ylim = ylim

    @property
    def m(self):
        return self._m

    @m.setter
    def m(self, m):
        self._m = m

    @property
    def lw(self):
        return self._lw

    @lw.setter
    def lw(self, lw):
        self._lw = lw

    def update_function(self, i, x, y, m, color):
        """ Definition of a matplotlib animation. """
        if i * m >= len(x) or i * m >= len(y):
            self.graphfunction.set_data(x[: i * m], y[: i * m])
        else:
            self.graphfunction.set_data(x[: i * m], y[: i * m])
            self.dot.set_data(x[i * m], y[i * m])

    def graph(self, interval=50):
        """ Definition of cycle FuncAnimation, which call animation. """
        self.graph_id = animation.FuncAnimation(
            self.figure,
            self.update_function,
            fargs=(self.x, self.y, self.m, self.color),
            repeat=False,
            interval=interval,
            frames=400,
        )


class SolveSystemOfADifferentialEquations:
    def __init__(self, k, angle, v0, m, ws, tlimit=20):
        self.k = k
        self.angle = angle
        self.m = m
        self.ws = ws
        self.v0 = v0
        self.v0_x = self.v0 * np.cos(self.angle)
        self.v0_y = self.v0 * np.sin(self.angle)
        self.kdivm = self.k / self.m
        self.time = np.arange(0, tlimit, 0.0005)

    def xmodel(self, X, t):
        x = X[0]
        dx = X[1]
        zdot = [[], []]
        zdot[0] = dx
        zdot[1] = -self.kdivm * dx + self.ws
        return zdot

    def ymodel(self, Y, t):
        y = Y[0]
        dy = Y[1]
        zdot = [[], []]
        zdot[0] = dy
        zdot[1] = -g - self.kdivm * dy
        return zdot

    def solveX(self):
        x = np.integrate.odeint(self.xmodel, [0, self.v0_x], self.time)
        return x

    def solveY(self):
        y = np.integrate.odeint(self.ymodel, [0, self.v0_y], self.time)
        return y


class MainCommunicationWithGui(QtCore.QObject):
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list, list)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(float, float, float, float, float)
    def update_values(self, ws, m, k, angle, v0):
        x, y = self.tosystem(k, angle, v0, m, ws)
        self.dataChanged.emit(x, y)

    def tosystem(self, k, angle, v0, m, ws):
        system = SolveSystemOfADifferentialEquations(k, angle, v0, m, ws)
        Xi = np.array(system.solveY())
        Yi = np.array(system.solveY())
        x = []
        y = []
        for j in range(1, len(Yi)):
            if Yi[j][0] > 0:
                x.append(Yi[j][0])
                y.append(Xi[j][0])
        return x, y


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.communicate = MainCommunicationWithGui()
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        try:
            ws = float(self.textEdit_1.toPlainText())
            m = float(self.textEdit_2.toPlainText())
            if m == 0:
                return
            k = float(self.textEdit_3.toPlainText())
            angle = float(self.textEdit_4.toPlainText()) * (np.pi / 180)
            v0 = float(self.textEdit_5.toPlainText())
            xlim = float(self.textEdit_7.toPlainText())
            ylim = float(self.textEdit_8.toPlainText())
        except ValueError as e:
            print("error", e)
        else:
            self.communicate.xlim = xlim
            self.communicate.ylim = ylim
            self.communicate.update_values(ws, m, k, angle, v0)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    canvas = Canvas(color=["blue", "green", "cyan", "magenta", "black"])
    w.communicate.dataChanged.connect(canvas.update_values)
    canvas.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for detail help, but when i click button, canvas dont shows graph, does not react to that

Comment: I solve that https://i.imgur.com/Pan42kA.png like this, but also thank you,